# How accurate are the real life references to advertising campaigns in Mad Men

Tags: mad-men

There are numerous real life firms mentioned in Mad Men. How accurate are these references - i.e. are all of the firms that are talked about real life firms (or only certain ones), and are the advertisements that are presented ones which those firms actually used (or are they only for the show).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Advertising in Mad Men, there is a treasure trove of information on the net relating to this here's a few links. 
Lemon for Volkswagen was a real campaign. So was Kodak Carousel however Don's ad is much better than the real advert. You can just about pick out all the real ones. Some of the Mohawk Airlines adverts are quite similar. Secor Laxative is made up Fillmore Auto Parts and Sugarberry Ham are made up too.
McCann is a real firm Sterling Cooper and Sterling Cooper Draper Pryce is not.
Seek and ye shall find.

http://www.stylist.co.uk/life/the-real-mad-men-ads
http://www.businessinsider.com.au/don-drapers-mad-men-ads-vs-the-real-thing-2014-4
http://time.com/3750986/mad-men-ads/
http://www.fastcompany.com/3010648/madvertising-a-peek-at-the-real-life-ad-campaigns-depicted-on-mad-men
http://advertising.about.com/od/advertisingtrivia/a/FantasyvsRealityMadMen.htm

And the list goes on it's all very interesting reading and good history once you start getting into this subject, for instance Julian Koenig who did a lot of the Volkswagen adverts was a bit of a genius and forward thinker.

[image]
[image]